# API Input Validation and Avoiding Big If Statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on ensuring my API works correctly when given bad or missing data.

I currently have an if statement that checks whether or not an input is missing. If yes, it presents a `false` and if not theres a big else block with code.

e.g.:

```
if (!req.body.email || !req.body.mobile || !req.body.gender ||
      !req.body.yearOfBirth) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Missing request body parts'});
} else {
     //Continue
}
```

What i want to ask is there a better way to do this in terms of code readability, having such a big else block with a lot happening in it works but to me seems a little 'unnatural'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use an array for the fields you are testing for:

```
var requiredFields = ['email', 'mobile', 'gender', 'yearOfBirth'];
if (requiredFields.every(function(field) { return req.body[field]; })) {
     //Continue
} else {
     res.json({ success: false, message: 'Missing request body'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do all of this, the most popular seem to be:

- [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)
- [validate.js](http://validatejs.org)

Both allow you to define a so called `Schema`, which is a representation of what you expect to receive and act on it.

Note that job was created by the hapi team (hapi.js is an alternative for express), and you may want to look into [the express-joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi) module to make it more suitable for use with `express`.

Answer (score 0):

You can smartly use `validate.js` [Declarative validations for JavaScript.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate.js)